# Get element being changed in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the element that is being edited?

HTML

```
<div contenteditable=true>
  <pre>
    <span class="1">First line</span>
    <span class="2">Second line</span>
  </pre>
</div>
```

When I'm editing "First line", how do I check which span class is being edited?

JS

```
window.addEventListener("input", inputHandler, false);
function inputHandler(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

Prints out the entire div class:

```
<div contenteditable=true>
  <pre>
    <span class="1">First line</span>
    <span class="2">Second line</span>
  </pre>
</div>
```

But I just want to get `<span class="1">First line</span>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Span element` can't have `input/keypress/keyup`... `events` and those `events` can't be registered on it. Although there are other ways to accomplish this, you could *alternatively* use `DOMCharacterDataModified` event, check the **snippet** below.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("edit");

div.addEventListener("DOMCharacterDataModified", inputHandler, false);

function inputHandler(e) {
  var elem = e.target.parentNode;
  alert("Element: " + elem.tagName + "  class name: " + elem.className);
}
```

```html
<div id="edit" contenteditable=true>
  <pre>
    <span class="1">First line</span>
    <span class="2" >Second line</span>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must affect the `contenteditable` attribute individually to each piece you plan to modify.
You'll have to choose how to add event listener to all of them. For instance, like this:

```js
var editables = document.getElementsByClassName('editable');
for (var editable of editables) {
  editable.addEventListener("input", inputHandler, false);
}
function inputHandler(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <pre>
    <span class="editable 1"  contenteditable>First line</span>
    <span class="editable 2"  contenteditable>Second line</span>
  </pre>
</div>
```